# Matplotlib animation with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I would like to have an animation where the plot has two subplots using matplotlib. The first subplot keeps displaying image frames (probably using pyplot.imshow) and the second subplot needs to plot an array dynamically (probably using pyplot.plot).

The idea is that the array plot displays some data corresponding to video frames. I want to visualize how the data in the array changes as the video plays.

I have written code that can play the frames as an animated video:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
display = []
for k in range(len(frames)):
    display.append([plt.imshow(frames[k],animated=True)])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, display, interval=400, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)
plt.show()
```

`frames` is a list of N frames from a video, each with shape (m,m,3). Let `arr` be an array of shape (N,1) which contains some data corresponding to each frame in `frames`.

I can't seem to figure out how to simultaneously display `arr` with `frames` as an animation. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!